# python django url shows old image when exachanging

Tags: django, image

when running the Django server and hitting the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/pictures/h2.jpg, I was getting the requested image (jpg).

Now I exchange the jpg by a file, which is also called `h2.jpg` but when I call the same [URL](http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/pictures/h2.jpg) again 
it still shows the old picture.

How to handle that?

I need to do it automatically by the backend or somehow --> without user action

`Django version 2.1.7`

Comment: Because your browser caches the image, press `F5 + SHIFT` in browser to reload all resources again.

Comment: try to add some number(like current datetime, randome number, etc...) at the end of file with `?`

ex: `h2.jpg?1234567` browser will understand that url is new and loads newly

Answer (score 0):

You can use this middleware

```html
from django.utils.cache import add_never_cache_headers

class NoCachingMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        add_never_cache_headers(response)
        return respons
```

from this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13489175/11027652

Answer (score 0):

So, now the new file has a timestamp included in the filename. By this I can first read all files available in the folder and then take the first one to create a NEW dynamic filepath.